# How to select column names based on mapping table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi there what i want to do it is: I've got 2 table 
 first one is

```
Person Table
PID | Name | Surname | Area1 | Area2 | Area3 | OwnerID |
1   | John | Doe     |   5   |   6   |   8   |    1    |
2   | Jack | Danniel |   8   |   2   |   4   |    2    |
```

second one is

```
Area Table
AID | Value | Name  | OwnerID |
1   |  Java | Area1 |    1    |
2   |  Orac | Area2 |    1    |
3   |  Delp | Area1 |    2    |
4   |  Css  | Area3 |    1    |
```

how can I query a result like that if I want to select  Owner1  ?

```
PID | Name | Surname | Java  | Orac  | Css   | OwnerID |
1   | John | Doe     |   5   |   6   |   8   |    1    |
```

Comment: Cry. I mean, don't do this! It will require messy *dynamic SQL* as SQL identifiers must be *fixed* at execution time to guarantee the "shape". It may be easier to do this transformation when the data is consumed on the client (e.g. change the relevant .NET DataTable column heading names). Alternatively, it may be better to use a *properly normalized schema* - that is, have no AreaX columns.

Comment: (Actually, this *may* also be possible without dynamic SQL by using [PIVOT/UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) - by first creating a normalized derived set - assuming the `Value` column in "Area Table" is confined to a fixed set of values, but not something I'd care to explore/use.)

Comment: What I mean by a "normalized schema" is to have the schema look like: `Person <1:M> PersonArea <M:1> Area`. Have both a "Person" relation and an "Area" relation and then a linking table ("PersonArea") between the two. A normalized approach would make general data consumption easier and allow PIVOT to be used in a final step to achieve the desired results. As with the previous comment, PIVOT requires that the set of pivoted column names are provided and only *dynamic SQL* can make this work over an arbitrary set-provided set of column names: avoid!

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH A AS (
   SELECT PID, Name Name1, Surname, Area, _Area, OwnerID OwnerID1
   from Person A
   unpivot (_Area FOR Area IN (Area1, Area2, Area3)) C
 )

 select PID, Name1, Surname, sum(Java) JAVA, sum(Orac) Orac, sum(CSS) CSS, OwnerID
 from A
 inner join Area B 
   on Area = B.Name
   and A.OwnerID1 = B.OwnerID
 pivot (sum(_Area) for Value in (JAVA, ORAC, CSS)) C
 where OwnerID1 = 1
 group by PID, Name1, Surname, OwnerID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7d17b/24)